# Mysql import using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to import a mysqldump file using the system command in PHP. Here's how I am doing it -

```
$command = "F:\System 1.1\server\mysql\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost -P 7188 -u username -ppassword <dbname> < F:\System 1.1\backup.sql";
system($command,$return)
```

The value of $return is 1. Is the syntax incorrect? Also, are there any other ways to import a full database via PHP?

*(I am giving the full path to mysql.exe because the users who will be ultimately using the program might not have mysql installed and present in the path.)*

Comment: have you tried whis command in cmd ?

Comment: `The system command is returning 1`  By this you mean `$return` is 1, or the function is returning 1 (which would be the last line of output)?

Comment: Igoris - I have tried it in cmd and it works.
Rocket - $return is 1.

Comment: @ChaosMaker are you running this PHP from the command line or web server? If web server, it may not have read access to backup.sql

Comment: Web server. So apparently it turns out that the system command doesn't work if there are more than 2 double quotes in the command!

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts:

- If the function returns 1 (true) this indicates success... I assume you have checked that it does not work?
- There is the source command in MySql, eg use database; source path_to_file; although this may not help in this case as you want to run mysql.exe directly.

Comment: `system` should return the last line of the output or FALSE on error.  `$return` is the return value.  A return value of anything that isn't zero is failure.  It's weird, but a return value of 1 is not success.

Answer (score 0):

Your file paths contain spaces in `F:\System 1.1`, and that is likely causing problems for PHP.  You should enclose them in quotes like the following. Double backslashes as path separators may be necessary too.

```
$command = "\"F:\System 1.1\server\mysql\bin\mysql.exe\" -h localhost -P 7188 -u username -ppassword <dbname> < \"F:\System 1.1\backup.sql\"";
//---------^^^^---------------------------------------^^^^ Also in the backup.sql path...
```

When PHP executes your unquoted command, it sees:

```
F:\System
```

and fails, because this is an invalid command.

Comment: okay. 
so when I echo the command here's what it looks like - 
    "F:\System 1.1\server\mysql\bin\mysql.exe" -h localhost -P 7188 -u username -ppassword <db_name> < "F:\System 1.1\backup.sql"

that is not working either?

Comment: @ChaosMaker Does Windows correctly parse the `-ppassword`? I thought it choked if there wasn't a space between.

Comment: yes I think, because I am generating the backup in a similar manner using mysqldump, and its generating the sql file correctly.